# Scraping error when looking to display element between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I'm doing some scraping on a website and after getting everything into an object I am trying to print the prices found in it but for some reason I can't go through the object array and I can't figure the error.

Everything is stored in `price`and then I've tried to go over it using `.each`, `.forEach` and I get nothing but errors:

I have a variable `$pagina`which is a jQuery Object:

```
var $pagina = $(data);
```

`$pagina` contains the entire html of the site.

```
var price = $pagina.find('#sub-graph-1 .price');
```

At this point, `price` contains an array like this `[<div class=​"price">​129</div>​,<div class=​"price">​172​</div>​]` what I want is to get those numbers between the `divs`so I try:

```
    price.forEach(function () {
        console.log( $(this).html() );
    });
```

I get:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'forEach'

The same happens with `.each` any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: is `$pagina` a string or jquery object?

Comment: jquery object `var $pagina = $(data);`

Comment: You accepted my answer though it should help only if `price` is an array and not a jQuery object. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery utils function

```
$.each(price, function(){
    ...
});
```

[**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

If `$pagina` is a jQuery object, it would be `each`.

Comment: He's asking about `price`, and he wrote he tried with `each`. but if it's really a jQuery object, it should work. I don't know... I'm confused.